# How do I completely remove bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am writing an internal company document in LaTeX (class `report`) and I do not want to have any citations, references or bibliography section. If I just omit the `\bibliographystyle`, the LaTeX compiler throws an error. And I just CANNOT find how to remove the bibliography section, google gives me bunch of links how to modify the bibliography, but not how to completely remove it. I have found a site which has a list of bibliography styles and "None" was not in the list. Your help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You don't want the bibliography, but what about citations inside the document to elements that would have been in the bibliography?

Comment: Don't you have a line like `\bibliography{something}`?

Comment: There's something seems a bit odd about your question: if you don't want citations or a bibliography, then don't add them to your document.  But this surely isn't your question.  Are you asking how to remove all citations and bibliography from a document that already has these?

Comment: How are you want to deal with citation commands that occur in a "textual" style, such as in "As argued by `\cite{someauthor}`, bla bla bla"? Should the entire first part of the sentence (before "bla bla bla") be removed?

Answer (score 3):

Presumably your document has `\cite` commands, which you want to disable.  This is done in the following way:

```
\renewcommand{\cite}[2][]{}
```

Note that `\cite` may have two arguments, one being optional.

Then you can either comment out `\bibliography` and `\bibliographystyle` or redefine them as well

```
\renewcommand{\bibliography}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\bibliographystyle}[1]{}
```